# Juju fails to download charm with proxy

Tags: juju, proxy

I've succesfully deployed juju-gui with :

```
juju deploy --to 0 juju-gui
```

and I add-machine as well

```
juju statustibo@maas:~$ juju status
environment: maas
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.23.3
    dns-name: wicked-beds.maas
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-a3ab8efc-f8a5-11e4-9317-0050dae12e81/
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=2 mem=4096M
    state-server-member-status: has-vote
services:
  juju-gui:
    charm: cs:trusty/juju-gui-27
    exposed: true
    units:
      juju-gui/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.23.3
        machine: "0"
        open-ports:
        - 80/tcp
        - 443/tcp
        public-address: wicked-beds.maas
networks:
  maas-eth1:
    provider-id: maas-eth1
    cidr: 172.16.1.0/24
```

and 30min later I can't deploy other charm

I've got this error

```
juju deploy mysql
ERROR cannot download charm "cs:trusty/mysql-25": Get https://store.juju.ubuntu.com/charm-info?charms=cs%3Atrusty%2Fmysql-25: http: error connecting to proxy http://spike-dmz.aql.fr:3128: dial tcp: lookup spike-dmz.aql.fr: no such host
```

All my nodes can reach internet, wget store.juju.ubuntu.com
I've added all the proxy settings to my environments.yaml

Any idea why juju don't want to use my proxy ?

Answer (score 1):

The nodes use MAAS as their DNS, and MAAS doesn't seem to know how to resolve spike-dmz.aql.fr.

Have you tried configuring an upstream DNS server in MAAS? Go to settings on the top right, scroll down to `Upstream DNS used to resolve domains not managed by this MAAS` and fill that in with the DNS server of your network, see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I already set an upstream DNS server in MAAS settings.
Any other idea ?

Comment: Login on the bootstrap node and see if that can resolve (and connect to its port 3128) spike-dmz-aql.fr

Comment: Are your nodes on an isolated network?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in juju and is now fixed in 1.22 and up.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1403225